Cannot deserialize json in list of .net object
I would like to know if there is a possibility to deserialize the first node items in the List items in the conditions.cs. When I am trying to deserialize that, I have a conditions object with all the json in the Items list. My goal would be to not affect the properties in Conditions.
Example :

Conditions.cs
[Serializable]
public class Conditions
{
    public Conditions()
    {
        Items = new List<object>();
    }

    public List<object> Items { get; set; }
}

Json to deserialiaze
'items': [
              {
                'items': [
                  {
                    'q': {
                      'id': null,
                      'weight': 0,
                      'name': 'Original Search',
                      'originalSearch': true,
                      'value': 'murder'
                    },
                    'dWim': true,
                    'qLang': 'NaturalAnd',
                    'parseAlgorithm': false,
                    'suggestCorrections': true,
                    'autoCorrection': false,
                    'fuzzyMath': false,
                    'fuzzyMatch': false,
                    'includeFrenchUri': false,
                    'termUnitParse': null,
                    'suggestionCount': '1',
                    'synonyms': false,
                    'equivs': true,
                    'highlight': true,
                    'anyAttr': []
                  }
                ],
                'id': null,
                'recallQueryToken': null
              }
            ],
            'anyAttr': []
          }";


I don't really know, but XmlRoot/XmlElement doesn't really sound like json.

I don't really see the problem. Deserialize the complete json and just get the first item from the array...

The attributes you are using change the behavior of the BCL XmlSerializer. You are using the NewtonSoft JsonSerializer.

I have updated the conditions class. My goal is to deserialize from a json class not xml. The issue in my case is that the first item in my "items" properties contain only one item which is the remaining json not been deserialized

You need to create a class Item that has public properties for all the JSON keys and their values. And then change Items to public List<Item> Items.

We need a bit more information to help you.  1) Your JSON is malformed.  Upload it to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com and you will see many errors.  2) Your question doesn't seem to include your call to deserialize, so it's not clear what serializer you are using and how you are using the returned value.  Might you please [edit] your question to share a full [mcve] including well-formed JSON + your call to deserialize it (as text, not as a screen shot)?  Thanks!

I recommend downloading the Newtonsoft.Json package from NuGet. You can then use the following code to work with JSON data without needing to define classes for each JSON object.
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>("YOUR JSON STRING");

The provided JSON structure is somewhat unstructured; however, to access the "name" field, you can use the following code:
obj["items"][0]["items"][0]["q"]["name"]);

